# Using neuronalnet for clasification

Tags: r, neural-network, rstudio

I am trying to use neural networks with the `neuralnet` package, for a base with binary response. The problem is that apparently only works with numeric response.

```
# Load data
data(cats,package = "MASS")
str(cats)
'data.frame':   144 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Sex: Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Bwt: num  2 2 2 2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 ...
 $ Hwt: num  7 7.4 9.5 7.2 7.3 7.6 8.1 8.2 8.3 8.5 ...
```

fit neuronal net model

```
library(neuralnet)
nn <- neuralnet(formula = Sex ~ Bwt + Hwt, data = cats)
Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

Some suggestions to adjust and predict, a variable with binara response using the `neuralnet` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently one way is to return the variable in type numeric or integer, the problem is that at the time of making the predictions, it will not throw an integer. However, the prediction can be recalculated with ifelse, to obtain the appropriate result.

```
cats$Sex <- as.integer(cats$Sex)-1
nn <- neuralnet(formula = Sex ~ Bwt + Hwt, data = cats, hidden=3)
plot(nn)
```

[image]

```
pred.nn <- compute(nn, cats[,-1])
res <- ifelse(pred.nn$net.result > 0.5,1,0)
caret::confusionMatrix(as.factor(res),as.factor(cats$Sex))
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 31 11
         1 16 86

               Accuracy : 0.8125                
                 95% CI : (0.7390483, 0.8726502)
    No Information Rate : 0.6736111             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.0001470219          

                  Kappa : 0.5615697             
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.4414183268          

            Sensitivity : 0.6595745             
            Specificity : 0.8865979             
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7380952             
         Neg Pred Value : 0.8431373             
             Prevalence : 0.3263889             
         Detection Rate : 0.2152778             
   Detection Prevalence : 0.2916667             
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7730862             

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

Comment: This is a thorough answer and should probably be accepted over mine.  By the by, 0.5 may not be the optimal classification threshold - it may or may not be worthwhile looking at the caret calibration function.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the factor to binary data:

```
cats$Sex.binary <- as.numeric(cats$Sex) - 1
table(cats$Sex.binary)
 0  1
47 97

nn <- neuralnet(formula = Sex.binary ~ Bwt + Hwt, data = cats)
```

Then to make predictions with the model:

```
new.cats.data <- data.frame(Bwt=2, Hwt=2)
nn.pred <- compute(nn, new.cats.data)
nn.pred$net.result
ifelse(nn.pred$net.result > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

Note that 0.5 may not be the optimal classification threshold for this data.